# In postgresql. How can I know if query returned more than 1 row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which can return 0,1, or more rows.

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A(v_x integer[])
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$ 
declare 
x_part integer;
x_part2 integer;
x_sum integer;

begin
        select a,b,sum(qty) into x_part, x_part2,x_sum
                from tablet
                where location= any (v_x)
                group by a,b


       ..... more actions....
end;
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I have two problems:

1. if the query return more than one row I can not save the result into `x_part,x_part2,x_sum`.
2. How can I tell the number of rows returned?

Basically what I need is if there is more than 1 row to get out of the function with error msg, if there is 1 or 0 rows.. keep going with the function operation.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the keyword STRICT within the SELECT INTO line as covered here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW  in the postgresql manual.

essentially your call becomes:

```
select a,b,sum(qty) into STRICT x_part, x_part2,x_sum from tablet where location= any (v_x) group by a,b;

...  -- Rest of your function code here

-- Exception block added at the end of the code, only called if there is an exception anywhere within your function
EXCEPTION
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Too many rows!';
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Perhaps another solution would be to add a LIMIT 1 to the end of your query to guarantee no more than a single row is returned?  although this might mask a problem? ** - leaving this here as referenced by comment, but acknowledge this isn't valid option in this instance

HTH

Comment: I can't use `Limit 1`. My goal isn't to alter the results to fit my needs.. on the contrary... I need to know if I have more than 1 row. I'll try it with strict.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make the syntax clearer, was originally a bit confusing (my PostgreSQL is a bit rusty :) )